# How to handle owning references to GCD dispatch queues in malloc'ed memory

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I am adapting a client Linux app (in C) that keeps a linked list of malloc(ed) structs, each of which holds a pthread (POSIX thread).

Apple strongly discourages you from using `POSIX` threads, so I'm adapting it to use concurrent `GCD` dispatch queues instead.

The source is going to be maintained across both Linux and iOS, so I'd like to limit the structural changes.

To keep the changes to a minimum, I was just going to replace a linked list of structs containing pthreads to a single `malloc`ed struct that contains a pointer to a concurrent GCD dispatch queue created with `dispatch_queue_create()`.

However, it just occurred to me that that might not work due to `ARC`. By default, `ARC` doesn't know anything about owning references to object types in structs, especially not those that are created with `malloc()`.
Isn't there a way to get ARC to track strong references contained in structs and/or arbitrary memory blocks? I have a vague memory of Apple adding such a thing, but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Why the down-vote? Did I fail to describe my problem clearly? If you think my question is somehow not up to SOs standards, please explain your thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it if you compile that as Objective-C++ source code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
struct Data {
    dispatch_queue_t queue;
};
```

Objective-C

```
$ clang -x objective-c -fobjc-arc -c test.m
test.m:3:19: error: ARC forbids Objective-C objects in struct
        dispatch_queue_t queue;
                         ^
1 error generated.
```

Objective-C++

```
$ clang -x objective-c++ -fobjc-arc -c test.m
```

No errors.

Please take a look at [Clang Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting document](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership-qualified-fields-of-structs-and-unions).

> A program is ill-formed if it declares a member of a C struct or union to have a nontrivially ownership-qualified type.
>
> This restriction does not apply in Objective-C++.

**UPDATED**

You can do it with C++ `new`/`delete`. Or if you want to use `malloc`, you need to call destructor of the struct.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <new>

@interface Test : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t queue;
@end

@implementation Test
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
        self.queue = dispatch_queue_create("test", NULL);
    return self;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Test dealloced");
}
@end

struct Data {
    Test* test;
};

int main()
{
    NSLog(@"stack ===================");
    {
        Data d;
        d.test = [[Test alloc] init];
    }
    NSLog(@"stack end ===============");

    NSLog(@"new =====================");
    {
        Data* d = new Data();
        d->test = [[Test alloc] init];
        delete d;
    }
    NSLog(@"new end =================");

    NSLog(@"placement new ===========");
    {
        void* p = malloc(sizeof(Data));
        Data* d = new(p) Data();
        d->test = [[Test alloc] init];
        d->~Data();
        free(d);
    }
    NSLog(@"placement new end =======");

    return 0;
}
```

result

```
stack ===================
Test dealloced
stack end ===============
new =====================
Test dealloced
new end =================
placement new ===========
Test dealloced
placement new end =======
```

Comment: Using Objective-C++ avoids the compiler error, but doesn't solve the memory management issue. I still need my dispatch queue to be owned somehow so it doesn't get deallocated.

Comment: I decided to side-step the issue and simply save strong references to the dispatch queue(s) elsewhere and remove them from the malloc'ed struct.